# Create an OpenLayers layer using GetCapabilities info in JSON format

Tags: openlayers, wmts, getcapabilities

There is an [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html) on how to create `WMTS` layer using `GetCapabilities` info. However I do not find how to create layers from `GetCapabilities` info which is in `JSON` format. `OpenLayers` API does not seem to have capabilities parser for layers other `WMTS` let alone parser for capabilities in `JSON` format. Does creation/mapping of of layer options has to be done manually when capabilities are in `JSON` format?

[image]

Comment: WMTS standard defines only XML format for GetCapabilities and every compliant server must support it. Your need is special and you may be on your own with it.

Comment: There is no standard JSON format specified for WMTSCapabilities.  In the example ol/format/WMTSCapabilities is used to parse the XML into an object (which could be stringified as a JSON) which is then used by optionsFromCapabilities.  If your JSON is compatible you could use the response.JSON() result directly in optionsFromCapabilities.

Comment: Do you have any example of an OGC service giving a GetCapabilities response as JSON?